# How to hide files and directories in terminal

Tags: command-line

I would like to know If i want to hide my private files and folders on my storage minus setting password like how i do it in windows with "atrrib" command

Comment: What does this `attrib` thing do? Remember, we don't know Windows here. How hidden do you need these to be? Impossible to see or just hard to see?

Comment: There is no hidden attribute in Linux, instead you can add a dot `.` in the front of the file (or directory) name, thus the file will not be displayed unless you are not using `ls -a` within the command line or `Ctrl+H` within the file manager. If you want to make your files private you need to setup right filesystem permissions or make them really private by using encryption - encrypted partition, encrypted directory or encrypted archive.

Comment: @terdon, it manipulates file/folders attributes within Windows: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-hide-files-and-folders-windows-10

Comment: @pa4080 yes, so how hidden are they? Who can see them? Who can access them? My main point is that users shouldn't expect us to know what some thing from another operating system does. Brian, please [edit] your question and explain what you need so we can understand. Don't assume we know anything about Windows.

Comment: The question would be better if you explained exactly what you want instead of merely linking someplace else and hoping we'll correctly guess which features are important to you. Links tend to go stale quickly, making them useless for future reference.